# Oracle Sql LISTAGG with CASE

Tags: oracle11g, listagg

I am trying to add a LISTAGG function to the below query so that the output can be a single value, separated by commas.Can someone advise how to add the LISTAGG function to it.

```
SELECT CASE A.ATTRIBUTE_NAME
WHEN 'EA' THEN 'EMAIL ADDRESS'
WHEN 'CP' THEN 'Company'
WHEN 'OG' THEN 'Organization'
END AS USER_DETAILS
FROM USERS A LEFT OUTER JOIN DETAILS B
ON A.ID = B.USER_ID
WHERE USER_NAME LIKE '%John%'
```

Comment: Do you just mean that you want to make the case expression the first argument to listagg? I'm not sure why that is a problem, or if you mean something else. What have you tried and what happened? It doesn't look like it would be very useful output, so maybe sample data and expected result would help explain what you're really trying to do.

Comment: USER_DETAILS
EMAIL ADDRESS
Company
Organization
The above result that I am getting should converted as - EMAIL ADDRESS,Company,Organization. I tried to give my above query as the first expression of LISTAGG but did not work. Can you provide the exact query

Comment: You should show us your attempt and what 'did not work' means. Wrong result? An error? And please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48022584/edit) to add information.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you simply want to put the case expression inside the `listagg()` call:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(
  CASE A.ATTRIBUTE_NAME
    WHEN 'EA' THEN 'EMAIL ADDRESS'
    WHEN 'CP' THEN 'Company'
    WHEN 'OG' THEN 'Organization'
  END,
  ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A.ATTRIBUTE_NAME) AS USER_DETAILS
FROM USERS A LEFT OUTER JOIN DETAILS B
ON A.ID = B.USER_ID
WHERE USER_NAME LIKE '%John%'
```

Although it looks like it should be referring to `B.ATTRIBUTE_NAME`; perhaps you got that wrong modifying the code for posting. And you might want to order the items in the list differently.